# Is it possible to introduce magnetic monopoles without breaking $∇ · B = 0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, magnetic-moment, magnetic-monopoles

In another word, the net magnetic charge is always zero everywhere, which means magnetic field is still strictly source free. On the other hand, the net magnetic current jm can be nonzero, which means constant magnetic current can induce persistent solenoid electric field (although time varying magnetic field can induce solenoid electric field, it can’t maintain the field indefinitely because the magnetic field strength can’t be arbitrarily large).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

If you have a magnetic monopole then, by definition, there is some closed Gaussian surface $S$ over which $$\oint_S \vec B \cdot d\vec S \ne 0$$ which by implies that $$\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec B \ dV \ne 0$$ where $V$ is the volume enclosed by $S$. For the latter equation to be true then $\nabla \cdot \vec B$ cannot be 0 everywhere in $V$.

This does not mean that magnetic currents are impossible, but a field with magnetic currents that do not violate $\nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$ would not be considered to be monopoles as the $\vec B$ field would still have a 0 monopole term in the spherical harmonic expansion. It is possible that some specialty I am not familiar with uses the term "magnetic monopole" to mean something different than the first term in a spherical harmonic expansion as I use it. That specialty may consider a magnetic current to imply monopoles, but it would be different from the usage I know.

Comment: Setting up specific situations could theoretically have Div B = 0, with monopoles existing, its just that they'd have to occupy the same point in space. ( also the fact that at soon as time begins the distribution would fly apart and seperate. so wouldn't really be what OP is asking though

Comment: If they occupy the same point in space then it wouldn't be a monopole field. I.e. if you expand such a field in a standard multipole expansion the monopole term is 0. To my understanding that is what "no magnetic monopoles" means.

Comment: Yes, however the question isn't "If the field obeys $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$, can there be a monopole field?".It was, COULD we introduce monopoles without violating $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$. I agree there would be no monopole field, however to make current non zero whilst obeying $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ would require the existence of monopoles regardless, just occupying the same space such that the net divergence is zero ( if you can even define such a current density function in the first place)

Comment: Obviously my assumption is assuming monopoles cause divergence in the B field, and we can superpose charge density function. In the case we can superpose them, each seperate function causes a divergence in the B field ( monopole exist) but the sum results in a net zero divergence of the B field. I think the superposition of density functions is quite displeasing regardless.

Comment: I am curious if nonzero jm is possible in condensed matter with quasi monopoles.

Answer (score 2):

"Net magnetic charge is zero everywhere"
"Magnetic current is non zero"

Can be done using

$$\rho_{m} = -\vec{P} \cdot \nabla \delta^3(r)$$

Where $$\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt} ≠ 0$$

Here, $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} ≠ 0$ . So magnetic monoples would still exist. However the net charge about any volume, will be zero.

This charge density is reflective of 2 monopoles infinitely close together.

**Fundamentally:**

$\nabla  \cdot \vec{J}_{m} = -\frac{\partial \rho_{m}}{\partial t}$

If magnetic monopoles didn't exist $\rho_{m} = 0$

Then $\nabla \cdot  \vec{J}_{m} = 0$

A point charge cannot have this for a non zero $\vec{J}_{m}$.  So fundamentally this cannot happen.

**Specific situations:**

Situations described by $\nabla \cdot \vec{J}_{m} = 0$  Could have a net divergence of B at any point being zero. This could theoretically have a non zero current.

Any closed loop would suffice.
Imagine there being stationary magnetic monopoles, in a sea of moving monopoles with opposite charges. Net charge density everywhere is zero and thus no divergence of B anywhere.

The current density function in this scenario of ($\rho_{m} = 0, \vec{J}_{m} ≠ 0$)

Would take the form:

$\vec{J}_{m} = -\rho_{m} \vec{v}_{1} + \rho_{m} \vec{v}_{2}$

This requires 2 different current density functions to occupy the same space, the net function would not in the form $\vec{J}_{m} = \rho_m \vec{V}$ So would, in my opinion, not really be anything fundamental. As assuming all real distributions follow this, would require still, that monopoles exist, just occupying the same space.

Comment: If you want to interpret $\vec P$ as a dipole moment, you should change the sign of your first equation: $\rho_m = -\vec P \cdot \nabla \delta^{(3)}(r)$

Comment: Changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. To understand why, you need to visualise what vector equations really mean.

**$\Delta B = 0**: Take any small volume. 'Number of field lines' entering this volume will be equal to 'number of field lines' exiting this volume.

(Field lines are just a tool for visualising field. So number of field lines is not a well defined quantities. On other hand it is a powerful tool to visualise fields. We are going to use it)

This law follows directly from property of magnetic field lines that it always forms closed loop. If a field line enters a small volume, it will leave it at some point.

**Magnetic Monopole**: It is a point from which magnetic field lines emerge (or sink).

We can see that a field which emerges from a point or sinks at a point is incompatible with a field which **always** forms closed loops!